# How to find max connections available in Redis and how many are used and how many are free?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching, redis, jedis

We are using Redis from the Spring boot app and we are getting below alert like flood

```
Exception occurred while querying cache : class org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException Message: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the poolCause: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the poolMessage:Could not get a resource from the pool",
```

is it because of that their are no connections in the Redis Server ? or any other reason ?

How to find number of connections max available ? How to find how many are free ?

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

> Could not get a resource from the pool

You have ran out of connections in Jedis pool on client side. Possible fixes:

1. Return connections to the pool properly (`pool.returnResource()`), if you are not doing it. Don't hold them when they are not needed. Don't disconnect regulairly. Be sure that commons-pool version is at least `1.6`.
2. Increase pool size.

   ```
   JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
   poolConfig.setMaxTotal(...);
   ```
3. Increase the time to wait when there are no connections available.

   ```
   poolConfig.setWhenExhaustedAction(GenericObjectPool.WHEN_EXHAUSTED_BLOCK);
   poolConfig.setMaxWait(...);
   ```

**Update**:

For server-side limitations see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51539038/78569