# how many total connection or max connections are available in Redis Server?

Tags: redis

How many total connections are or max how many connections are present in redis ?

How many connections are busy ?

How many connections are free waiting for the requests ?

which commands or configuration i need see to answer above questions ?

**Am asking total / max connections not clients**

Answer (score 45):

Clients ARE connections. Redis doesn't know if two connections are from the same client.

### Current

```
info clients
```

> # Clients
>   connected_clients:2
>   client_longest_output_list:0
>   client_biggest_input_buf:0
>   blocked_clients:0

### Maximum

```
config get maxclients
```

> 1) "maxclients"
>   2) "4064"

If you want to change maxclients, you may do so in conf file, or at runtime with the command `config set maxclients <val>`, but note that this value is limited by available file descriptors, so run appropriate `ulimit -n <val>` before.

Comment: so , config get maxclients  , is giving 10000 as return value , means maximum 10000 connections are available in redis server , and info clients  is giving connected_clients as 35 , means 35 total connections are being used at present  , can you please confirm my interpretation ?

Comment: When I ran the `config` command in `redis-cli`, I got this error `(error) ERR unknown command 'config', with args beginning with: 'get', 'maxclients'`. Is `config` still available?

Comment: Oh, I think it is because my redis server is hosted by ElasticCache. It does not expose the `config` command.

Answer (score 7):

As of writing this in Redis 2.6 the default limit is 10000 clients but can be over-ridden in the redis.conf

If the number that we require is more than the maximum number of file descriptors that can be opened by the File System, then REDIS sets the maximum number of clients/connections to what it can realistically handle.

Read more about it [here](https://redis.io/topics/clients#:%7E:text=In%20Redis%202.4%20there%20was,the%20maxclients%20directive%20in%20Redis.)

Comment: Good catch with the file descriptor limit!